# How to redirect Warnings and ERROR messages to logfile instead stdout?

Tags: logging, julia

It is understood that custom user logs can be written to logfile  using Logging package's @info.

Please guide me in redirecting julia Warning and ERROR messages while invoking commands`using <PACKAGE_NAME>` messages to logfile instead stdout!

Update1:

at shell level, `/path/to/julia/script 2>> /path/to/log/file` appends julia warnings and errors to log file and suppresses them at prompt.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions from https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Logging/#Logging-1? In particular running `global_logger` with your custom logger before `using` command? If this is not clear let me know and I can expand in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I followed as explained in the reference. It writes the logs only after closing the io, but not incrementally! Also getting warnings and errors at prompt.  Is there any option to write logs near real time incrementally!

Comment: You have to `flush` the stream to commit all currently buffered writes.

Comment: flush(io) writes the logs in buffer (as of prior to the call) to the file and later generated logs are written at the close(io) call (note: the test scripts are simple ones). 
Whether flush(io) should be invoked frequently to write logs to file? 
As it seems to be buffering and writing to file, would some incidents go un-recorded in logfile in unforeseen circumstances (like crash...)?

Comment: You can either use `stdbuf` utility in Linux (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) to change stream buffering or register function that closes the stream using `atexit`. Unfortunately you cannot use `do` syntax when opening a stream as you want to run global-only statements like `using`.